# React redux unable to find props in component event after using mapStateWithProps

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I have tried a lot but i couldn't figure out what is the issue.

The props in the component is coming as empty even after adding mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps property.Whenever i run the below code i get following error.
`projList.js:94 Uncaught TypeError: _this2.props.addNewProj is not a function`

My component class is given below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { addProj } from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import C from '../constants';

    class projList extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                title: ''
            }
        }

        render(){
            const {title} = this.state;
            return(
            <section className='proj-list-container'>
                <div className='form'>
                    <label>project Title</label>
                    <input type='text' onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({title: e.target.value})}}/>
                    <button className='submit' onClick={()=>{this.props.addNewProj(title)}}>submit</button>
                </div>}
            </section>
            );
        }
    }
    const mapStateToProps = (state, props) =>
        ({
            projLists: state.addProjToList
        })

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
        ({
            addNewProj(projObj) {
                dispatch(
                    addProj(C.ADD_PROJ, projObj)
                );
            }
        });
    export default connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(projList);
    export default projList;
```

My actions file is

```
import C from './constants'
    export const addProj = ({title, endDate}) => {
        return ({
            type:C.ADD_PROJ,
            payload: {
                title, endDate
            }
        })
    }
```

And my store file is :

```
import C from '../constants';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

    export const addProjToList = (state=[], action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case C.ADD_PROJ :
                return [
                    ...state,
                    action.payload
                ]
            default : return state
        }
    }

    const appReducer =  combineReducers({
        addProjToList
    });
    export default (initialState={projList: []}) => {
        return applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore)(appReducer, initialState);
    }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a "this" problem. Can you try and define the onClick handler this way:
`onClick={this.props.addNewProj.bind(this,title)}` ? If that's not the problem then look into your addProj import, try an absolute import instead of a relative.

Comment: I tried bind it doesn't work and import looks fine.

Comment: Can you create the handler as a method of your component this way 
`handleClick = () => {...}`, attach it it this way: `onClick={this.handleClick}`, and within the body of handleClick: `console.log(this)`, `console.log(this.props)` and `console.log(this.props.addNewProj)`? we'll have a better understanding of what happens.

Comment: why are you exporting twice at the bottom of your component, you dont need this `export default projList;` if you have connected?

Comment: above comment is correct. You only need the first `export default`. Second one overwrites the first and exports the inner component with no connection to store.

Comment: @SGhaleb thanks it is because i have exported projList thins issue arises.